# Why NavigateFunction type is shown cannot be found when assigning it to react-router navigate?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to migrate my functions from function components to a separate file.

Function component code:

```
const Signup = () => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();   

  return (
    ............
    <Form className="SignupForm" onSubmit={() => onSignupHandler(navigate)}>
  )
}
```

Here is the `onSignUpHandler` function code:

```
export const onSignupHandler = (navigate: NavigateFunction) => {
  // Some code ...............
};
```

I am trying to assign `navigate` type of `NavigateFunction` but I get error as `Cannot find name 'NavigateFunction'.`

Comment: Did you import `NavigateFunction` where you are trying to use it? Please share a complete [mcve] for what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing it the imports. Add to the file where `onSignUpHandler` is:

```
import { NavigateFunction } from "react-router-dom";
```